# How to forward a request to a different rest controller with Spring Reactive and WebFlux

Tags: java, spring, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm trying to forward a request to a different internal endpoint from a WebFlux RestContoller.

I don't want to send a redirect to the client, but let a different controller handling the current request. See the code below:

```
@RestController
public class MyController {
  
   @PostMapping("/start")
   public Mono<MyReponse> start() {
          return myService.retrieveSomething().flatMap(something -> {
               if(something.isBlank()){
                  retrun createMyResponse(); // returns Mono<MyResponse>
               } else {
                  // forward to "/continue"
               }
           });
   }
}

@RestController
public class MyOtherController {
       
       @PostMapping("/continue")
       public Mono<MyReponse> continue() {
           // do something and return Mono<MyResponse> 
       }
}
```

With Spring Servlet I'd do something like:

```
protected void start(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext()
      .getRequestDispatcher("/continue");
    dispatcher.forward(req, resp);
}
```

Is it possible to do the same in Spring Reactive with WebFlux?
Had a look at the official documentation but couldn't find an example. I tried to use objects like DispatcherHandler, ServerWebExchange, ServerHttpRequest, ServerHttpResponse but couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Spring WebFlux [Functional Endpoints](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-fn) that "*a lightweight functional programming model in which functions are used to route and handle requests*".

```
@Bean
RouterFunction<ServerResponse> startRoute() {
    return route(POST("/start"), req -> startHandler(req));
}

@Bean
RouterFunction<ServerResponse> continueRoute() {
    return route(POST("/continue"), req -> continueHandler(req));
}

Mono<ServerResponse> startHandler(ServerRequest serverRequest) {
    return myService.retrieveSomething()
            .flatMap(something -> {
                if (something.isBlank()){
                    ...
                } else {
                    return continueHandler(serverRequest);
                }
            });
}

Mono<ServerResponse> continueHandler(ServerRequest serverRequest) {
   ...
}
```